# How to find scaling to get minimum positive integer proportion?

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, linear-transformations

Suppose we have x is a strictly positive vector and y=*b**x where b is a positive scaling scalar. The problem is to find the function to get the scaling factor *b* such that y becomes minimum positive integer.
 Here are some examples:
x=[1, 3, 1.5] then y=[2, 6, 3];
x=[0.5, 0.25, 0.75] then y=[2, 1, 3];
x=[1.75, 1, 0.5, 2] then y=[7, 4, 2, 8];
x=[0.5, 0.333, 1, 2.75] then y=[500, 333, 1000, 2750]
My question: what is the function of the scaling factor *b* such that y=*b**x becomes the minimum positive integer proportion for any positive vector x?

Comment: Are the entries of $x$ rational?

Comment: yes, the entries are all rational numbers

Comment: If $x=[3,3,3]$, will you take $b=\frac13$?

Comment: yes, if x=[3,3,3] then y=[1,1,1]

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Clear denominators)

Write your vector $x$ entries in fractions (in simplest form), then $b$ will be the lowest common multiple (LCM) of the denominators.

For example write x=[0.5, 0.25, 0.75] as $x=[\frac 12, \frac 14, \frac 34]$.

Since LCM(2,4)=4, $b_1=4$. Then $y=[2,1,3]$.

Step 2: Simplify)

At this stage $y$ should already have all entries integers, then divide throughout by the GCD of all the integers.
E.g. if $x=[3,3,3]$, $b_2=1/3$ to get $[1,1,1]$.

(As pointed out by peterwhy)

Overall, the scalar $b$ will be the product of the $b_1b_2$ used in the two stages.

Comment: It appears that you also have to consider the GCD of the numerators.

Comment: Ah yes, that is correct

Comment: the actual length of x can be very long. I can find vector nominator N and vector denominator D but I am not sure about how to get the LCM because LCM requires two vectors.

Comment: Are you finding out the LCM by computer or by hand? LCM is defined for more than two integers: see for instance https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/factors-multiples/least_common_multiple/v/least-common-multiple-lcm

Comment: I mean, even if $x$ are not all integers from the begining, it is probably still necessary to consider the GCD of the numerators. Consider $x=[4/3, 2]$.

Comment: I am using Matlab. There is built-in GCD and LCM

Comment: @Hajar I believe what you need is: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/240937

Comment: I tried your answer above using this code but it does not work. It produces integer but not the minimum: function y=num2whole(x)
if nargin<1,
    x = [1   , 3    , 1.5;
         0.5 , 0.25 , 0.75;
         1.75, 1    , 0.5 ;
         0.5 , 0.333, 2.1]
end
A=x;         % copy
D=ones(size(A)); 
while (sum(sum(abs(double(int64(A))-A)))~=0), 
    A=A*10;  % numerator
    D=D*10;  % denominator
end
k = lcm(A,D)
g = gcd(A,D)
y=x.*k.*g